# Why does my sourdough loaf not get an ear

Tags: sourdough

My loaves seem to have good oven spring, I think. I think that because it rises up on the sides and forms an oval sort of shape each time.

My cut often expands but doesn't open up much or form an ear.

[image]

Todays partly opened. I dont know if I am doing the cut wrong. Maybe too deep, not deep enough.  I do try and do 45 degree angle.

[image]

Does anyone have some advice to improve this please?

Comment: If you are using a home oven, did you add steam? By throwing some water into the oven as you close it, either onto the oven floor or onto a tray. This really helps.

Answer (score 3):

with no photo of the crumb it's hard to know whether there's also a proofing issue but irrespectively let me tell you that it's notoriously difficult to get a consistent ear at home unless you bake the bread in some sort of hot enclosure (dutch oven, cast iron pot with lid etc). That is my experience at least. Sure, the cutting makes a difference so as to have a nice ear but the moisture is the main culprit: your oven cooks the outside of the bread too fast before the temperatures reaches the air in the inside, so when the bread expands air is sealed in and doesn't get the spring it can. Cooking in an enclosure keeps the moisture from the bread close to the crust thus keeping it soft for a bit longer which is when the inside gets hot and expands. This whole thing happens the first 5-10' of baking so if you don't get an ear by then, it's game over.

I have been baking sourdough 2ice a week for about three years now, here's a bread that didn't quite open well enough (together with its crumb to show that it's properly proofed and folded)
[image]

and here's one that opened beautifully:
[image]

their only difference being that the second was baked inside an enamel pot (the baguettes always get an ear cause they are baked on their little baguette baking trays).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your top photo on the left hand side you'll see you do have an ear at that one spot. The trick is to make your cut at an angle to give the edge a shelf to build up.

I'm betting you cut straight down into the dough and not at a sharp angle.

Answer (score 2):

given the advice, I tried the following:

- sprayed water over the dough before putting it in the oven
- put a large thin metal pan on the shelf below the pizza stone when I turned the oven on
- put plenty of water into the pan 10 mins before putting the dough in
- first 20 mins had the pan in, then removed for another 20 mins.

here is the result[image]

will work on improving the cut, looks like I should have gone <s>further</s> **deeper** around on the left

**UPDATE**

so a few weeks on with more practice I have made some adjustments

- spray the cut with a bit of water just before it goes in the oven
- put a large thin metal pan on the shelf below the pizza stone when I turned the oven on, I put the stone slightly to one side and the pan slightly to the other. (don't know if this helps, but helps with the pouring speed)
- Have the kettle fully boiled just before I am going to put the dough in the oven
- Put the dough on the pizza stone, THEN pour the boiling water into the hot pan underneath the stone and quickly close the oven door.
- do NOT do the main cut too deep, that seemed to cause  the bottom of it to go hard or something. At least the later, more shallow cuts seem to be doing better

this is how the latest loaf came out
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Sourdough ear is made by folding and pinching the bread to the shape.
ALso this process is more successful in a dutch oven.
You have to score a diagonal line.
Also steam plays a role in sour dough bread making.

Comment: Uh.... no? If you work with the folding method, you bake the loaf seam side up and aim for a controlled tear along the weakness at the seam (but don’t pinch!) and don’t cut at all. But that doesn’t produce an “ear” as asked for in the question. And the other approaches have been mentioned before and with more details in the previous answers. Please don’t post answers repeating already given advice, upvote these posts instead.

Comment: @Stephie I read this answer differently. It may be a matter of terminology.  Fist, the poster suggests that the loaf is folded and pinched into shape.  This is true for most sourdough...certainly the loaves the OP pictured.  The "skin" of the loaf needs to be taut. This answer doesn't state which side is up during baking, but the "pinched" side is usually up in the proofing basket, and down in the oven. It is also true that an ear is improved by baking in a dutch oven.  This is where the role of steam comes in.  The direction of the line/scoring, perhaps, has less merit.

Comment: @moscafj still the ear isn’t produced by any folding or pinching, the rest of the answer is significantly less detailed than existing ones. I have no issues with posts that struggle with the language, as long as I can find the information I am happy to do clarifying edits.

Comment: @Stephie in my experience shaping plays a role.